# managesieve - default sieve not applying

Tags: dovecot, roundcube, sieve

I set up my mail server on Debian 11 (postfix, dovecot, spamassassin, roundcube) and I got an issue with managesieve.

In "90-sieve.conf" I set:

```
sieve_default = /var/lib/dovecot/sieve/default.sieve
```

Then I edited the file with a spam check, to move mail to the junk folder and ran the following command:

```
sievec default.sieve
```

The problem is that whenever I create a new user, the default sieve I find in Roundcube is actually named "roundcube" and it's empty.. So where do I set the default sieve other than in the previously shown conf?
I didn't edit the roundcube managesieve plugin's configuration file.

Thanks